# Windows process hollowing/ Suspended process creation/ Waking up the suspended process

Tags: windows, process, suspend

Suppose Process A creates another Process B in a suspended state and after some time process A wakes up B. How do we identify the process that had a handle to process B so as to wake it up?

Comment: Maybe there's a WMI event for this that could be monitored. Otherwise there's no reliable way to know which processes requested the suspend count on a thread to be incremented or decremented. For the thread to resume, the suspend count has to be decremented to 0.

Comment: Aren't handles nothing but data structures? EnumProcess() receives the PID of all processes running in the system. Is it possible to pass the PID of a running process to OpenProcess() to obtain its handles?